# Not able to run the code

Tags: vba, excel

These are two different codes I am using to generate chart and do the calculation using two different buttons.

Code1: To generate charts, works okay

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'PURPOSE: Create a chart (chart dimensions are required)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cht As ChartObject

    'Your data range for the chart
      Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A27:B113")

    'Create a chart
      Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
        Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
        Width:=650, _
        Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
        Height:=250)

    'Give chart some data
      cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

    'Determine the chart type
      cht.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

    End Sub
    Code 2: To do the calculations

    Sub GenerateCharts()

    [D32].Value = "AA"

    Range("D31").Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("B27:B113"), ">=56") / Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B27:B113"))

    [H35].Value = "All Defects"
    Range("I35").Formula = "=SUM(B27:B113)"

    [H36].Value = "Percentage(%)"
    Range("I36").Formula = "=(1-(I28/I29))*100"

    [H28].Value = "Non Kaizens"
    **Range("I28").Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("'Machine 4th QTR’!V:V", "'Machine 4th QTR'!B:B","", "'Machine 4th QTR’!V:V'"), "<56"**)

End Sub
```

I have got two issues here.
1.  Code 1 runs fine, coming to Code 2, all it does is it calculates the values. 
When I run the Code 2, error is shown in the part in **BOLD**.  The **BOLD** part translates the formula shown below into VBA code.

```
=SUMIFS('Machine 4th QTR'!V:V,'Machine 4th QTR'!B:B,"",'Machine 4th QTR'!V:V,"<56")
```

This is the error message displayed:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid propert assigment

I cannot figure out what is going wrong in the last piece (highlighted one).

2. Can I embed both the codes into one so that I can perform both the operations with only one click.

Comment: Change `""` to `""""` or `TEXT(,)` and change `"<56"` to `""<56""`. You need to double up quotes within quoted strings or use alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Change `""` to `""""` or `TEXT(,)` and change `"<56"` to `""<56""`. You need to double up quotes within quoted strings or use an alternative.

If you want the formula in the cell, use a string representing the formula, not an evaluation (aka *result*) of the WorksheetFunction.SumIfs formula.

You needed a SUMIFS, not a SUMIF.

You were using back-quotes (e.g. `’`) not tick quotes (e.g. `'`) in some places.

```
Range("D31").Formula = "=SUMIF(B27:B113, "">=56"")/SUM(B27:B113)"
 ...
Range("I28").Formula = "=SUMIFS('Machine 4th QTR'!V:V, 'Machine 4th QTR'!B:B, TEXT(,), 'Machine 4th QTR'!V:V, ""<56"")"
```